# Blank page after attempt to insert

Tags: mysql

Whenever I try to insert data into my database 'users' I always get a blank page. It doesn't give me any errors, it doesn't include 'mainmenu.php', or return any feedback what so ever. Can someone help me out? Here is the code:

```
<?php

include("mainmenu.php");

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "*********");
if (!$con) {
   die('Connection failure.' . mysql_error());
   }

//Variable def
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$usrname = $_POST['usrname'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

mysql_select_db("users",$con) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (usrname, fname, lname, password, email) VALUES ($usrname, $fname, $lname, $password, $email)") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($con)

echo("Thank you for registering!")
?>
```

It looks right to me.

Comment: This isn't the answer you're looking for, but PLEASE learn how to parameterize your queries. Even MORE so if you're a newbie -- best to learn how to do things correctly from day one so you don't learn bad habits. If you have no idea what I'm talking about, google "SQL Injection" and "PHP parameterized queries" for help.

Comment: @Brennan: If only i could +10...

Comment: "bare with me" -- No, we're not getting naked with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't you getting any syntax error?

first

```
mysql_close($con)
echo("Thank you for registering!")
```

change to

```
mysql_close($con);
echo("Thank you for registering!");
```

second, please quote your $_POST and escape it properly
read this - [Escaping single quote in PHP when inserting into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687866/escaping-single-quote-in-php-when-inserting-into-mysql))

Comment: oops! forgot the semicolons! now it shows syntax errors. thanks a bunch!

Comment: no, now it says i have to use date_default_timezone_set() function, whatever that means. ill just look it up.

Answer (score 3):

No errors? Add this at the top of the script:

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all: Strings need delimiting:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (usrname, fname, lname, password, email) VALUES ('$usrname', '$fname', '$lname', '$password', '$email')";
```

Second: **never ever** pass un-checked user data into a database query. Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on each value first.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (usrname, fname, lname, password, email) VALUES ($usrname, $fname, $lname, $password, $email)") or die(mysql_error());
```

Use this instead

```
$insert_sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (usrname, fname, lname, password, email) " .
          "VALUES ('%s' ,'%s', '%s', '%s', %d); ",
           mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $usrname),
           mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $fname),
           mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $lname),
           mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, md5($password)),
           mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email),
           mysqli_insert_id($conn));
```

Then Query The Above String

```
mysqli_query($conn, $insert_sql);
```

Then a Conditionals

```
if($insert_sql){
$usrname = $_SESSION['user_id'];
//url.ext e.g could be "home.php" or "you.html"
//header is used for redirecting a page
header("Location: url.ext");
}else{
$msg = "error inserting";
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "?Message= ". $msg );
}
```