# Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given... what I do wrong?

Tags: php, mysqli

I try make php login but I get this error: `Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given,` what I do wrong?

register.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang"fi">
<head>
<link rel="icon" type='image/png' href='images/logo.png'>
<title>
asd
</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<!--reg alkaa-->
<form action="register.php" method="post">
<p><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
<p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
<p><input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
<p><input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Password">
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
$pass1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pass1']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
if($username && $pass && $pass1 && $email)
{
if($pass==$pass1)
{
    $connect = mysql_connect("mysql.example.com","username","password");
    mysql_select_db("my_database");
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('$username','$pass','$email');");
    echo "You have been registered.";
}
else
{
    echo "Password must match.";
}
}
else
{
echo "All fields are required.";
}
}
 ?>
<!--reg end-->
<Center>
<a href="index.php">
<h1>
asd
</h1>
</center>
<div id="main">
<h3>
 <div class="menu"> <a href="index.php">Etusivu</a> &bullet; 
 <a                                       </div>
</h3>
</div>
<div class="jonne"> 
</div>
<script src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I use 000webhost and this first time when I use mysql databases online.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You are mixing `mysqli` and `mysql` function.

If your are using mysql function then instead `mysqli_real_escape_string($your_variable);` use

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
$pass1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass1']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

If your using mysqli_* function then you have to include your connection to database into **[mysqli_real_escape function](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)** :

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($your_connection, $_POST['username']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($your_connection, $_POST['pass']);
$pass1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($your_connection, $_POST['pass1']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($your_connection, $_POST['email']);
```

Note : Use mysqli_* function since mysql has been deprecated. For information please read ***[mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)****

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) , the function `mysqli_real_escape_string()` has two parameters.

```
string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr ).
```

The first one is a *link* for a mysqli instance (database connection object), the second one is the *string* to escape. So your code should be like :

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($yourconnectionobject,$_POST['username']);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works perfectly:-

```
if(isset($_POST['signup'])){
$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['username']);
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['email']);
$pass1=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['pass1']);
$pass2=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['pass2']);
```

Now, the **$connect** is my variable containing my connection to the database. You only left out the connection  variable. Include it and it shall work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

[***mysqli_real_escape_string function***](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) requires the connection to your database.

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($your_connection, $_POST['username']);
```

**P.S.:** Do not mix ***mysql_* functions*** and ***mysqli_* functions***. Please use `mysqli_* functions or PDO` because mysql_* functions are deprecated and will be removed in the future.

Answer (score 1):

you are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`

use this `mysql_real_escape_string` like

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
```

**NOTE :** `mysql_*` is deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 1):

If you use the procedural style, you have to provide both a connection and a string:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $name);
```

Only the object oriented version can be done with just a string:

```
$name = $link->real_escape_string($name);
```

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) should hopefully make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

pass `$connect` as your first parameter in `mysqli_real_escape_string` for this first make connection then do rest.read here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this way instead of your way.

```
    addslashes(trim($_POST['username']));
```

Comment: For avoid the special characters use java script validation in front end.

Comment: That's not a safe way of escaping strings for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

There is slight change in mysql_real_escape_string mysqli_real_escape_string. below syntax

mysql_real_escape_string syntax will be **mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sample_var'])**

mysqli_real_escape_string syntax will be **mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['sample_var'])**

Answer (score -1):

Replace your query with the following:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('$username','$pass','$email')", `$Connect`);
```

Answer (score -2):

use `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead of `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

like so:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
```

Comment: mysql has been deprecated