# Php 5.4 to 7.1 : Mysqli_real_escape_string() 2 parameters, 1 given in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Im trying to convert my Wordpress theme from PHP 5.4 to 7.1

But... I still don't understand what's happening with this error :

> **Warning**:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2
>   parameters, 1 given in
>   **/home/myhost/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php** on line
>   **69**

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');


function cG($name){
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $_GET[$name]=stripslashes($_GET[$name]); 
    $name=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET[$name]);
    return $name;
}
```

I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636975/warning-mysqli-real-escape-string-expects-exactly-2-parameters-1-given-wh), but even I get the error... Any idea ? Thank you!

Comment: Did you var_dump  `$_GET[$name]`?

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

magic_quotes_gpc is deprecated as of PHP 5.3 and removed as of PHP 5.4 ... so your check here is useless ... And keep in mind that your connection string isn't visible inside the function, You'll either have to accept it as an argument or use global keyword which isn't a good solution.

Accepting as an arugment:

```
function cG($con, $name){
    $name=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET[$name]);
    return $name;
}

cG($con, 'something');
```

or using global keyword:

```
function cG($name){
    global $con;
    $name=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET[$name]);
    return $name;
}
```