# Phpmyadmin MySQL Syntax

Tags: php, sql, forms

If a value like this value :  **'s-Gravenhage** will submit into my database

Then the form is not submitted and i see a error:

**Error**: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's-Gravenhage',, '', '', '', '', '0', '0', '0', '', '', '', '', '19.05.' at line 2

Other values without : **-** and **'** are no problems!

I think it is because the ' and -

How can i fix this in phpmyadmin?

So this is the send.php (for a action form)

```
$link = mysql_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD); 

if (!$link) { 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link); 

if (!$db_selected) { 
die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error()); 
} 



$value = $_POST['firstname']; 
$value2 = $_POST['lastname']; 
$value3 = $_POST['city']; 


$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (firstname, lastname, city)
VALUES ('$value', '$value2', '$value3'')";



if (!mysql_query($sql)) { 
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
```

Comment: You need to escape your input. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687866/escaping-single-quote-in-php-when-inserting-into-mysql

Comment: Thank you very much, but where do i need to put the mysql_real_escape_string() function ?

Comment: can you post the code used to make the query?

Comment: Yes offcourse i will edit the post one moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See revised code below. Each input needs to be sanitised before being used in the query. This is also for security reasons. Read more about that here https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

```
$link = mysql_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD); 

if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link); 

if (!$db_selected) { 
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']); 
$value2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']); 
$value3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (firstname, lastname, city) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', '$value3')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) { 
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much! It Works! May God bless you! Have a nice day George! Byee