# Inserting a chat message into a database

Tags: php, mysql

So I use the following line of code to insert a chat message into my MySQL database:

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO group_messages (group_message_text,group_message_group_id,group_message_user_id) VALUES ('$message','$group_id','$user_id');");
```

This works great until the users tries to use characters like ' or emoji's. How do I handle that properly?

Comment: research for sql-injections, PDO, *_real_escape_string etc

Comment: You should try to use Prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

To store emoji's in your database you have to store it in `utf8mb4`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11840562/4248617).

You should also escape your text bevor storing it into the database. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2687891/4248617) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the Syntax error:

```
Please try using 
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO group_messages (group_message_text,group_message_group_id,group_message_user_id) VALUES ('".$message."','".$group_id."','".$user_id."');");
```

Hope this will help :)