# codeigniter : searching string with quotes( ' or " ) showing error

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, search

i am try to implement a search that but it shows error when I use Single Quotes like (manu's ,ramu's)

When I change my term part like `%".$term."%` and  use back quotes it shows same error.

**Query :**

```
 $this->db->select('*');    
 $this->db->from('tbl_doctor');  
 $this->db->join("tbl_specialisation", "tbl_specialisation.spec_id = tbl_doctor.spec_id",'left');
 $this->db->where("(tbl_doctor.dr_name LIKE `%".$term."%` OR tbl_doctor.district LIKE `%".$term."%` OR tbl_specialisation.spec_specialise LIKE `%".$term."%`OR tbl_doctor.place LIKE `%".$term."%` )");
 $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
```

and my error
[image]

Comment: use mysql_real_escape_string($term) and try

Comment: Use `$this->db->escape_like_str()` to escape the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need escape string before including it inside query string. Use  [$this->db->escape_like_str()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#escaping-queries) to escape string.

As you asked "why?", here is the explanation.

**Explanation :** When you are trying to add *anu's* in your search query its single quote(') is getting treated as end of string. escape_like_str() will automatically add slash() before any quote to prevent string from unintended termination. Escape That's why you need to escape the string before adding it inside your query.

```
$this->db->select('*');    
$this->db->from('tbl_doctor');  
$this->db->join("tbl_specialisation", "tbl_specialisation.spec_id = tbl_doctor.spec_id",'left');
$this->db->where("(tbl_doctor.dr_name LIKE '%".$this->db->escape_like_str($term)."%' OR tbl_doctor.district LIKE '%".$this->db->escape_like_str($term)."%' OR tbl_specialisation.spec_specialise LIKE '%".$this->db->escape_like_str($term)."%'OR tbl_doctor.place LIKE '%".$this->db->escape_like_str($term)."%' )"); 
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
```

Comment: the Single Quotes is issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Escape String to search. Try this below code with codeigniter function

> $this->db->escape_like_str($term)

New Code is

```
$this->db->select('*');    

$this->db->from('tbl_doctor');  

$this->db->join("tbl_specialisation", "tbl_specialisation.spec_id = tbl_doctor.spec_id",'left');

$this->db->where("(tbl_doctor.dr_name LIKE `%".$this->db->escape_like_str($term)."%` OR tbl_doctor.district LIKE `%".$this->db->escape_like_str($term)."%` OR tbl_specialisation.spec_specialise LIKE `%".$this->db->escape_like_str($term)."%`OR tbl_doctor.place LIKE `%".$this->db->escape_like_str($term)."%` )"); 

$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the string. Use [$this->db->escape_like_str()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#escaping-queries).

Try this code :

```
$this->db->escape_like_str($term);
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap $term variable with mysql_real_escape_string() in query.

Like : mysql_real_escape_string($term)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687866/escaping-single-quote-in-php-when-inserting-into-mysqlhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687866/escaping-single-quote-in-php-when-inserting-into-mysql)