# insert sql {"title": {...}} - escape?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, escaping

I'd like to insert the following to my database:

```
"INSERT INTO `table` (`column1`, `column2`, `column3`) VALUES (1, 2, '{"title": {"abc1":def","abc2":"def2" ...}}')";
```

How can I achieve that? I guess I have to escape the string but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: A quick search found this: https://ubiq.co/database-blog/how-to-escape-single-quote-special-characters-in-mysql/ and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687866/escaping-single-quote-in-php-when-inserting-into-mysql. Maybe try those suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements is what you want.

```
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('
Insert Into
    table
SET
    column1=:col1Val,
    column2=:col2Val,
    column3=:col3Val
';
  $stmt->execute([
    ':col1Val'=>'Value',
    ':col2Val'=>$someVar,
    ':col3Val'=>'{"title": {...}}'
  ]);
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    echo 'Row Inserted<br>';
} else {
    echo 'Row Not Inserted<br>';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

for example

```
Insert Into Person_Table (Firstname,Lastname,Age) Values ('Sahand','Golpour',25)
```

Use quotation marks only for the string data type

Comment: This doesn't answer their question in any way.